How to Implement Chat-Specific Vector Embeddings and Manage Token Limits in a Serverless Chat Application Using Azure?
Question:
I'm developing a chat application similar to ChatGPT using Azure's serverless model. The application includes several functionalities such as document upload, vector embeddings storage, and AI-powered responses. However, I'm facing multiple challenges and would appreciate any guidance or best practices.
Key Points:

Chat-Specific Vector Embeddings:
I want to store vector embeddings that are specific to a particular chat session. For example, when a user uploads a document to a particular chat, the files and their vector embeddings should be restricted to that chat only. I'm using Azure services for this purpose. What is the best way to implement this architecture? Should I store the embeddings in Azure Cognitive Search, or is there a better approach for chat-specific storage?

Handling Token Limits in RAG (Retrieval-Augmented Generation) Applications:
My application involves a RAG setup where users might upload multiple documents (e.g., resumes), and I need to retrieve information about all candidates simultaneously. However, when passing all the retrieved information from Azure AI Search to the OpenAI API, I encounter token limit issues, leading to 429 errors. I’m using Semantic Kernel for managing AI responses. How can I efficiently handle large responses within the token limits, or is there a better way to architect this process?

Response Speed Optimization:
The application's response speed is slower than expected due to the multiple functions that need to be executed sequentially. What strategies can I use to optimize the response time, particularly when using Azure Functions and Semantic Kernel?

Issues with Azure Search Indexers:
I am considering storing vectors in Azure Search, but I'm encountering errors when trying to create multiple indexers and indexes specific to each chat. Should I rely on Azure Search indexers for generating embeddings, or is it better to manually code the entire process (e.g., chunking, embedding, and storing)?


Any insights, especially from those who have implemented similar architectures in Azure, would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
